# IntelliJ doesn't recognize java project after cloning

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I've cloned my repo from bitbucket and I am trying to open it in IntelliJ IDE, but i can't set Debug Configuration, can't set Main class in Application menu. I can't also add new Java class into project. I think that Intellij can't recognize this project is Java.

Is it possible to make it right?

Comment: Have you tried the `import` option from the `files` menu?

Comment: I export settings from working project and import them to this. Didn't help, still not works. http://imgur.com/ZUy4E9e

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You have to mark your `src` directory as `Source Root`.

Right-click on the `src` folder and select `Sources Root`:

[image]

Then you'll see that the icons will change:

[image]

---

---

### EDIT

Check the output path by bringing up the `Project Structure` view.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I have another problem. First: http://imgur.com/L9Costd,gXOBUlr#0 and I mark "Use module compile output path from Project Structure/Paths and second: http://imgur.com/L9Costd,gXOBUlr#1 and no idea what to do...

Comment: Another good point to mention is which directory you attempt to open. If you click on the directory itself that stores the project things will auto configure and auto build. Ex: Open the directory via intellij that contains "ProjectName\src\main\java\etc" vs "Directory\ProjectName\src\main\java\etc"

Comment: Mark as "Source Root" `java` folder (from "src.main.java. .. ") works for me perfectly. Thx

Answer (score 7):

Similar to what maba said above, but if applicable you probably want to mark `main` and `test` as source & test source directories (respectively). That's a common project directory structure where literally marking `src` (parent of `main` and `test`) as source won't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, marking **src** folder as **'Source Root'** resolved the issue. Earlier intellij was not detecting java files.

Go to: Right Click --> src --> (Choose option) Mark Directory as --> Source Root.

Answer (score 1):

As a footnote, I've had what I thought of as small projects take well over 15 minutes to fully load into IntelliJ, and during this time the little status bar in the bottom right seems to be downloading dependencies (lots of Spring stuff) ... though most of them should have already been in my local ~/.m2 maven repo.

Maybe slow network, maybe the repo/proxy I was hitting was slow ... whatever, I'm just reminding people to check that status bar when opening a new project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer make sure you select a valid sdk in the "file/project structure" dialog.