# IntelliJ compiling errors, says packages dont exist when they do etc

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to swap over to IntelliJ from Eclipse. I started by importing in 1 of my Minecraft plugin projects into IntelliJ. I wanted to make sure everything was configured correctly before importing the rest. I have tried to compile the plugin into a .jar file, but nothing has worked, IntelliJ always spews out a massive amount of errors about importing my custom objects saying they don't exist when they clearly do. 
Errors can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/PxPHR8Tk. Every single error it throws when compiling is wrong, since the symbols and packages clearly exist in the project.

Comment: It would probably help to see something more than a pastebin. Also have a look at the settings mentioned there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088957/intellij-doesnt-recognize-java-project-after-cloning

Comment: Have you checked your project structure to ensure all libraries are referenced correctly?