# Android Studio can't recognize java file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

Why AndroidStudio can't recognize some java files in my project?

I have a FileInfo.java in folder , and Android Studio can't take it as a java file,but other java file can be recognized normally. My Project can build successfully.

Other Java class can't index this FileInfo class. Everywhere which use FileInfo are red text.

The issue seems like this.
[Android studio can't recognize java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGVSL.png)

How to solve this problem?

The files in my folder, FileInfo.java is normal java file, not end with
txt.
see this picture link
[my folder structure like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPuKt.png)

Part of file:
[part of FileInfo.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovmg8.png)

My Project can build successfully,all functions are normal. So It won't be wrong with my code or class semantics.
I have tried to rebuild and clean cache ,but it can't work.

My Android Studio version is

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 29, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.karateca.jstoolbox (1.10), com.kite.intellij (1.9.4), com.boohee.plugin.translation2 (2.0), PlantUML integration (5.13.0), org.jetbrains.kotlin-js-inspection-pack-plugin (0.0.10), zielu.gittoolbox (212.8.9), SequenceDiagram (2.1.10), cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id (0.2.5)
```

Comment: have you seen how all the other files don't show an extension? Quite likely, that file is called FileInfo.java, but it's extension is .txt, making it FileInfo.java.txt

Comment: Can you hover over the red text and paste a screenshot , as to what does the compiler say ??

Comment: sorry, it's my first time to use stackoverflow .  I don't to know how to paste a sreenshot ,  I only paste picture link , please check the link

Comment: Have you looked at what @Stultuske said? They are likely right

Comment: my file is end with .java  .   see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPuKt.png)

Comment: Please check file associations in "Settings | Editor | File Types". Probably "FileInfo.java" is linked to text file type.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means that the java file doesn't contain a class named FileInfo.

Comment: My Project can build successfully,all functions are normal. So It won't be wrong with my code or class semantics

Comment: Create a new Java Class and paste the code in it and try

Answer (score -1):

Watch if you wrote FileInfo.java the same as the code in the File

```
class FileInfo
```

or try to build it once or close and reopen IntelliJ thats the most likely Problem.

greetings

Comment: My Project can build successfully,all functions are normal. So It won't be wrong with my code or class semantics. I have tried to rebuild and  clean cache ,but it can't work.

Comment: Try this bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088957/intellij-doesnt-recognize-java-project-after-cloning

Comment: I have tried , but  the issue still exist

Comment: create a new class by intelliJ and copy paste the code

Comment: but it has to be the same name than the old one